# Why does this Scala placeholder not work

Tags: scala

Given these case classes:

```
case class FeatureDistance(id: Long, distance: Double)

case class SearchResult(score: Float, id: Long)
```

Why does this not compile?

```
val distances = List[FeatureDistance](FeatureDistance(1L, 10f)) 
val results = distances.map(SearchResult(0f, _.id))
```

But this does:

```
val results = distances.map(fd => SearchResult(0f, fd.id))
```

The compilation error says: `missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$3) => x$3.id)`

Is it because `_` is only scoped to the map function so it's not visible in the `SearchResult.apply` call?

Comment: I just encountered this the other day.  I have no idea why it is that way, but I suspect it has to do with the scoping of the underscore character.  Since it's really only just syntactic sugar, it shouldn't matter for your actual performance, though.

Answer (score 1):

After doing a bit of research, I found a [post on the old scala forums](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/2916.html) that contains this quote:

> When you use "_" as a place holder for an anonymous parameter of a function, the scope of that function is the innermost parenthesis containing it.

So, it's just a question of scope.  I suspect this has to do with problems that could otherwise result from having nested function calls that use more than one underscore.  For instance:

```
//suppose we have some x:List[List[Int]]
x.map(_.map(_ + 1))
```

Comment: yeah that's what I thought, it's interesting though because we could do something like x.map(y => y.map(y => y + 1)) - although we would probably be shot for doing so! :D

Comment: That would be horrendous!